# Windows 7 laptop freezes after an hour

Tags: windows-7, windows, freeze, defragment

I have a laptop with Windows 7 Enterprise. If I leave alone for an hour then the
laptop freezes.  I have checked all the power options so that nothing kicks in (like hibernate, etc.) after an hour. I finally just checked my event log after it happened again today, and there is only one entry, about an hour after I stopped using it:

> The disk defragmenter successfully completed defragmentation on System
>   Reserved

Could that be the culprit? If so, what should I do to fix it? If not, what else can I try?

**Edit**

In case this can help someone else, I was able to disable defragmenation on just the System Reserved disk. Now a defrag can still happen on my C: drive.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to know if the defragmenter of Windows is the culprit you can disable it (temporarily).

1. Click Start.
2. Click Control Panel.
3. Click System and Security
4. Under the `Administrative Tools` section at the bottom, click `Defragment your hard drive`
5. Click `Configure schedule`
6. You may need to grant permission to open the `Configure`-dialog.
7. Un-check `Run automatically (recommended)`
8. Click OK

and see if it hapens again after an hour.

Comment: FYI: After clicking System, on my Win7 laptop, it's: Performance Information and Tools -> Advanced Tools -> Open Disk Defragmenter.

Comment: That's correct. I had my `View by Category` on. If you switch to `Small/Large Icons` it's where you found it. You could also type `defrag` in the search-box :)

Comment: I won't be able to test this until the end of the day. If it works, I'll come back and accept this answer. I did give you +1 for the tip.

Comment: By the way, if this works, does that mean I can never defragment my hard drive? Or maybe I can, but I just need to be prepared for my computer to freeze when I defrag?

Comment: It means you found what causes the freeze and we can check further what the real reason is. There could be a solution found on the net or you could use another defragmenter (like the free [Defraggler](http://www.piriform.com/defraggler) from Piriform)

Comment: Your suggestion worked. See my edit for how I was able to still keep defragging the C: drive. Thanks again!